# Displaying Success Message in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I delete all selected checkboxes in a repeater
it should show a success message. The code below isn't working. How can I fix this?

```
protected void btnDeleteAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rpCategory.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)
        rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved");

        if (((CheckBox)rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved")).Checked)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox = (CheckBox)rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved");

            SqlConnection cnn = system.baglan();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where  SubCategoryID is null", cnn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

            DeleteMsg.Visible = true;

            Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx");
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are redirecting the user to a different page (or reloading the current one) so the `DeleteMsg` you are setting to visible is never shown.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand *when* and *where* you're showing the alert.

You are changing the visibility of a control in the page which is executing the request on the server, and immediately you redirect the user to another page, so the control will never be rendered.

Or you redirect the user *after* showing the control (per example adding an accept button and redirecting when the user clicks on it) or you just pass a variable to the second page and instruct it to show the message.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting the user to a new page so anything you do on the page that is handling the postback won't be shown.

One way to show the message is by passing it as a parameter to the next page. Then check in that page if there is a message to show.

So `Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx");` would become `Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx?Message=Deleted Stuff");`

Then make sure there is a control the Categories.aspx page to show the message. In your case something like `<div runat="server" id="DeleteMsg"></div>`. In the `Page_Load` of Categories.aspx do something like:

```
if (Request["Message"] != null)
{
    // Note that you shouldn't just print anything from the URL here but this should get you started.
    DeleteMsg.InnerText = Request["Message"];
    DeleteMsg.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    DeleteMsg.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: thank u much, its working well but i dont want to use label. how can i do it with ID? i want to use this --> DeleteMsg.Visible = true;


 **<div class="alert alert-info"  id="DeleteMsg" runat="server"  visible="false"></div>**

Comment: @Shkupjane No problem, just replace my `MessageLabel` with `DeleteMsg` and use `InnerText` or `InnerHtml` property instead of `Text` property like so: `DeleteMsg.InnerText = Request["Message"]`

Comment: @Shkupjane: Updated the answer to use your `div` instead. Since it seems to be working for you, please mark as answer :)

Comment: if (Request["DeleteMsg"] != null)
{

    DeleteMsg.InnerText = Request["DeleteMsg"];
    DeleteMsg.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    DeleteMsg.Visible = false;
}

Comment: Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx?DeleteMsg");  it doesnt work

Comment: i want to show message in **div tag** so how can i fix he `responsive.redirect` ??

Comment: You need to add the message to the `DeleteMsg` parameter like so: `Response.Redirect("Categories.aspx?DeleteMsg=insert your message here");`

Comment: But i want to show Message in'div' so i have Message in div class